# Weaker sufficient condition for this property?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Under what condition can we guarantee that $f(x) \geq 0 \Longrightarrow f(x') \geq 0$ for $x < x'$?

Obviously, if $f$ is increasing, this property holds. We can also show that the condition $f(x) = 0 \Longrightarrow f'(x) > 0$ also guarantees this property. However, both conditions are too strong for my application. The former does not hold in my application and the later rules out the possibility that $f(x) \equiv 0$ for all $x$. Is there any weaker condition to guarantee the desired property?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe elaborating on you application helps others to give an answer. In particular one that is useful to you

Comment: Is $f$ necessarily continuous? Does it have any other properties that might be useful?

Comment: @user295959  How about $\{x: \ f(x)  < 0\} = (0, a)$ for some $0\le a \le 1$?